# Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND] [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Why i Cannot find module **'C:\Users\Josh\Desktop\ethiks-api\src\graphql\schema'** in imported from **C:\Users\Josh\Desktop\ethiks-api\src\server.js** ?? did i miss something? please help me to configure this error. thanks, the error **Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND] [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module**

```
|-graphql
  |_schema
  |-coach
  |-country
  |-event
|-service
  |_readSigned
    |_index.js
  |_uploadSigned
    |_index.js
  |_index.js
|-server.js
```

this is my grapql/schema.js

```
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime'
import merge from 'lodash.merge'
import { gql } from 'apollo-server-express'


import Coach from './coach'
import Country from './country'
import Event from './event'


const typeDef = gql`
  type Query
  type Mutation
`

export default {
  typeDefs: [
    typeDef,
    Coach.typeDefs,
    Country.typeDefs,
    Event.typeDefs,

  ],
  resolvers: merge(
    Coach.resolvers,
    Country.resolvers,
    Event.resolvers,

  )
}
```

this is my server.js

```
import express from 'express'
import helmet from 'helmet'
import cors from 'cors'
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-express'
import schema from './graphql/schema'
import service from './service/index'


const app = express();

const {
  SERVERPORT = 8085,
} = process.env

app.use(helmet())
app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json({ limit: '50mb' }))
app.use(express.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb', extended: true }))

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs: schema.typeDefs,
  resolvers: schema.resolvers,
  context: (req) => ({ req }),
  debug: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
})

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))
app.get('/generate-upload', service.uploadSigned)
app.get('/read-upload', service.readSigned)

server.applyMiddleware({ app })

process.on('unhandledRejection', (error) => {
  console.log('Unhandled Rejection', error)
})

app.listen(SERVERPORT, () => {
  console.log(`App listening to ${SERVERPORT} in ${process.env.NODE_ENV}`)
})
```

this is my service/index.js

```
import uploadSigned from './uploadSigned'
import readSigned from './readSigned'

export default {
  uploadSigned,
  readSigned,
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it called `schema.js`? Because in your directory tree, it just says `schema`.

Comment: sorry, my mistake, it should be, schema.js